# Question about how networked users work

Tags: serveradmin, open-directory

As I'm waiting for my new gleaming iMac to arrive, I'm considering buying OS X Server since it's only $20 now and offers Open Directory.

We have two MacBook Pros, so I'd like to have all of us able to log into any of the 3 Macs with our ID.

1. Can I simply switch from a local user to a network user without losing my home directory contents?
2. Is it just my home directory that is mirrored on the server? Or is it all the applications I've installed etc. For example, if I install an application on Laptop A will it show up on Laptop B?
3. I assume that when I have the laptop somewhere that the server is not available, that I can still get to all my home directory contents.  They will then magically sync back up when I get back to my regular network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get some feedback over at StackExchange:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221782/detail-on-how-os-x-networked-users-works

Closing this thread.